# Java (gson и float) как избавиться от экспоненты?

Tags: gson, json, float, java

Здравствуйте, уважаемые.

Подскажите, как в джаве можно избавиться от экспоненты при выводе числа куда-либо?

Допустим, у нас есть:

```
public static float testFloat2 = 0.0000000006F;
```

Через GSON я это дело сериализую, получаю на выходе:

```
"testFloat2": 6.0E-10
```

Что можно сделать, чтобы выводилось так:

```
"testFloat2": 0.0000000006
```

Comment: почитайте про класс Formatter

Comment: Прошу прощения, а как его применить непосредственно к GSON?

Comment: Забыл добавить. Сериализую так:

    result.add(field.getName(), gson.toJsonTree(field.get(null), field.getType()));

либо так (из сериализатора другого класса):

   result.add(field.getName(), context.serialize(field.get(category), field.getType()));

field получаю рефлексией.

Comment: В принципе можно это сделать касмтомным сериализатором для float и Float, возвращаеть форматированную строку. Но уж очень не хочется кавычек в результате - нелогично.

Comment: @Евгений Карпов, эммм... не понимаю, а зачем вам это нужно? Json это всего лишь формат представления данных - ну да human-readable, ну и что? Зачем вам читаемость полей?

Comment: Ну, хотя бы для того, чтобы в экстренных случаев конфиги можно было подправить "руками", не вникая в дебри неудобочитаемых экспонент.
PS: и, да, я просил совета по решению, а не попыток отговорить :) само собой, если это слишком сложно сделать, то я оставлю как есть.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11119094/switch-off-scientific-notation-in-gson-double-serialization

вот аналогичный вопрос с ответом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ дан в комментариях к вопросу. Закрываю. Модеру просьба снести этот ответ и закрыть вопрос...